# Can't get data from Ajax response

Tags: json, ajax, api

So I'm having this ajax GET request to my API:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//id=$("#id").val();
url="api.php/fcomment/"+5;
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: url,
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function (data) 
    {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);
        $('.greeting-content').append(data.comment);  
    }
});
});
```

I get JSON data, results of it is:

```
[{"id":"5","comment":"Test","post_date":"18:17 18.05.2017","forum":"2","user":"0"},{"id":"8","comment":"Test2","post_date":"18:05 24.05.2017","forum":"2","user":"7"}]
```

I would like to get values out of JSON format, but nothing is added to div. If i add JSON.stringify around data then I get entire JSON but I need each attribute by itself

Comment: use JSON.parse(data);

Comment: $.each method , loop over the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your accessing `data.comment` it's is undefined access like this  `data[0].comment`

```
 $('.greeting-content').append(data[0].comment);
```

You can use `$.each` to get all data

```js
data = [{"id":"5","comment":"Test","post_date":"18:17 18.05.2017","forum":"2","user":"0"},{"id":"8","comment":"Test2","post_date":"18:05 24.05.2017","forum":"2","user":"7"}];

console.log(data[0].comment);

$.each(data,function(i,v){
  
       console.log(data[i].comment);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah I already tried with JSON.Parse but then I get error in console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: glad to help you @Miko

Answer (score 0):

You are getting collection you need loop over it

```
    $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (i, data) {

                var row = data;   // data.comment
                console.log(row);
            });
```

OR

```
 $.each(data, function (i, data) {

                var row = data;
                console.log(row);
            });
```